# Seeking a different way in using Reflection or Introspection in Python

Tags: python, reflection, introspection

I'm refactoring some code, and I thought I could use a bit of Reflection! So, I have this for now:

```
def f(self, clazz):
    [...]
    boolean = False
    if hasattr(clazz_instace, 'some_attribute'):
        setattr(clazz_instace, 'some_attribute', True)
        boolean = True

    if boolean:
        result = getattr(clazz_instace, 'another_method')(None, request=request)
        return result['objects']

    sorted_objects = getattr(clazz_instace, 'One_more_method')(request)
    result = getattr(clazz_instace, 'another_method')(sorted_objects, request=request)

    return [...]
```

My question is about the strings I used to indicate which method I'm searching for regarding to the clazz_instance. I'd like to know if there's another and very best way to do what I did (In a dinamic way to be specific)? I mean, intead of putting method's name like strings directly as I did, would be really nice if I could verify  dinamically those methods, differently.

Could you give some nice ideas? How would you do it?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? If the attribute names are all string literals, this is just a more complicated way of accessing them directly (possibly with `except NameError` in one of the cases). If they're not, where are they coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An instance's method is nothing more than a `function` object stored in the instace's `__dict__`. This said, you are doing correct to find them, except that maybe, the class indeed has the attribute corresponding to your argument string, but is not a function, is just another type instead.

If you depend on this, I recommend you refactor the *instance's function looking* code into a helper method:

```
import types
def instance_has_method(instance, name):
    try:
        attr = getattr(instance, name)
        return isinstance(attr, types.FunctionType)
    except AttributeError:
        return False
```

Once you have this function, your code will be more concise because now you're sure that the attribute is indeed a function and can be callable.

The code above checks if the attribute is a function. If you want something wider, you can check if it's a `callable` like this: `return hasattr(attr, '__call__')`.

In python, this is basically how you check for attributes inside classes. I don't think there's nothing wrong with your approach and not another more clever way to do reflection.

Hope this helps!

Comment: ... Yep! Thanks! As always I seek for good tips and lessons. Here now, you gave me a such great idea I didnt think about it! Thanks!

Comment: If a function is not defined in a class, but is defined instead in one oft its base classes, it is missing from `__dict__`. So `getattr` works better here, because it properly traverses the inheritance graph (which is not easy to do correctly, trust me).

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to understand what you are trying to achieve.

`getattr(clazz_instace, 'One_more_method')(request)` is just a fancy way to say `clazz_instace.One_more_method(request)`.

Use of `getattr` is reasonable when you don't know the method name in advance, that is, if your method name is variable.

Also, `setattr(clazz_instace, 'some_method_inside_this_class', True)` turns alleged `some_method_inside_this_class` into a *scalar* attribute inside that class, having a `True` value. Probably this is not what you planned to have.

My best effort to understand your code is this:

```
def f(clazz):
  # if clazz is capable of better_processing, use it:
  if hasattr(clazz, 'better_processing'):
    return clazz.better_processing(...)
  else:
    return clazz.basic_processing(...)
```

BTW what `getattr` gives you is a callable method, you can directly use it, like this:

```
method = getattr(clazz, 'better_method', clazz.default_method)
# if 'better_method' was available, it was returned by getattr;
# if not, the default method was returned.
return method(clazz_instance, some_data...)
```

Comment: Good points you have! But, I ask in my question: if there is another way of searching class's methods without searchin 'em by their names as strings... And oh yeah, that `setattr(clazz_instace, 'some_method_inside_this_class', True)` is an attribute and not a method, that's my fault. Anyway, thank you for your good points! I'll think about it too!

Comment: What _other_ identifier (but name) for a method comes to your mind? Its signature? Signatures in Python are pretty uninformative. If you're looking for something like interfaces, maybe [ABCs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html) could help you describe them.